# Pass variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a variable locally defined in my View. I am setting it to 1 under some conditions. I want to pass this variable to the script in order to have a condition based on it that decides if an audio is played or not.

How can I pass alarm variable to my javascript?

```
@{
    int alarm = 0;
 }

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if (ViewBag.Dtype == "1")
   {                
      alarm = 1;
   }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('player').play()});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the Razor variable into javascript variable. 
Like below, storing `alarm` into javascript variable `jsAlarm`. Now you can use `jsAlarm` for your condition check.

```
@{
    int alarm = 0;
 }

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if (ViewBag.Dtype == "1")
   {                
      alarm = 1;
   }
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsAlarm=@alarm;
    $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('player').play()});    
</script>
```